# meaning of whole

Tags: vocabulary

> In my neighborhood in Pawtucket, it’s common to run into your
>   neighbors on summer evenings. Lots of people eat dinner on their
>   porches, or go for walks up and down the streets, or drink wine in the
>   yard as the sun sets. My partner, Nate, and I like to walk. As we do,
>   children bound up to us and begin to chatter excitedly. They may show
>   us the praying mantis they caught in a jar, or the shells they
>   collected on the beach that day, or give us the details about the
>   birthday party down the street. We talk with their parents, talk about
>   nothing in particular, nothing too important, but we laugh often. As
>   the orange sun sets and the purple-grey twilight takes its place, it
>   is comforting, fortifying conversation.
>
> These simple, random interactions make me feel ***whole***.
>  (Curt
>   [Columbus, The Importance of Neighbors)](http://thisibelieve.org/essay/142184/)

I suspected that ***whole*** above may mean [“full; complete”](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/whole) but the dictionary says this is only before noun.  Is the whole [“not broken or damaged”](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/whole)?

Comment: I think this is a good question, but you can probably treat **feel whole** as an idiom.

Comment: @snailboat There's no need to treat **feel whole** as idiomatic; this is a less-common but still standard use of the adjective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I disagree with the OALD's tagging of the definition as "only before noun". English grammar has a number of general rules (such as putting adjectives before nouns) that are frequently ignored for stylistic or historical reasons ("attorney general").

In this case, **whole** does mean "complete", with the suggestion that this is the way things ought to be, even if they often aren't.

Comment: You disagree that **whole** has attributive-only uses.  Let's test that out by turning the OALD's attributive examples into predicative examples: *We drank a whole bottle each.* → **The bottles we each drank were whole.*  Hmm.  That didn't work very well.  *We offer a whole variety of weekend breaks.* → **The variety of weekend breaks we offer is whole.*  No, I don't think you can reasonably disagree that there are uses of this word that are attributive-only.

Comment: @snailboat On definition 2, I don't disagree at all. I think that definition 1 (or it least its list of examples) is a conflation of usages wherein "complete" is not reasonably distinguishable from "unbroken", and the *whole* entry fails to account for the particular construction of **whole** as a predicate adjective, which is commonplace and uses the word for its standard meaning.

Comment: @snailboat, what you said is the very reason I upload this question. I've not found the predicative examples for whole.